# Sidebar element look like be part of main content. How to achieve this hover effect?

Tags: html, css

I tried to look for this effect in stackoverflow, but I have no idea, how developers call this kind of hover effect also no idea how to achieve it. I tried to use few kinds of solutions but everything was fail. Is it possible to do this in pure CSS at all?

[Link to image of this effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEInp.png)

I mean that kind of `border-radius` at right side of element?

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="app">
      <nav class="navigation">
        <div class="nav-content">
          <ul>
            <span class="logo">Logoo</span>
            <hr />
            <a href="#">
              <li class="nav-item">
                Home
              </li>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <li class="nav-item">
                Rate plans
              </li>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <li class="nav-item">
                Bookings
              </li>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <li class="nav-item">
                Apartments
              </li>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <li class="nav-item">
                Pricing
              </li>
            </a>
            <hr />
            <a href="#">
              <li class="nav-item">
                Support
              </li>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <li class="nav-item">
                LogOut
              </li>
            </a>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <main>
        <div class="main-content"></div>
      </main>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.app {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 80%;
  grid-template-rows: 100%;
  grid-template-areas: "nav main";
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

nav {
  grid-area: nav;
}

main {
  grid-area: main;
}

.navigation {
  padding: 0 0 0 40px;
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
}

.nav-item {
  padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
  border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
}

.nav-item:hover {
  background-color: var(--main-color);
  color: black;
}

ul {
  background-color: var(--main-color);
}
```

This is the effect I have obtained so far, but that's all...

[Link to image of my work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDdA7.png)
also https://jsfiddle.net/q93mc8kz/

Comment: what is the name of website in the image

Comment: it's mockup from dribble.

Comment: I have achieved this so far https://jsfiddle.net/ps8xf7nr/

Comment: Nice! I did it too, look at fiddle at end of this topic. The most difficult thing is that right side of element looks like it was widen when hovered. This image shows it https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEInp.png

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to do that

Comment: I have added an answer please check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I did it.

-I have used **::before** and **::after** to achieve this.

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Rishabtyagi/hq078gdx/14

```css
.app {
  display: grid;
  //commented//grid-template-columns: 20% 80%;
  grid-template-rows: 100%;
  grid-template-areas: "nav main";
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}



nav {
  grid-area: nav;
}

main {
  grid-area: main;
}

.navigation {
  padding: 0 0 0 40px;
  background-color: brown;
}

.nav-item,.nav-item1,.nav-item2 {
  padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  background-color: brown;
  
  
}

.nav-item::before,.nav-item1::before,.nav-item2::before{
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
  content:'';
}

.nav-item::after,.nav-item1::after,.nav-item2::after{
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
  content:'';
}

.nav-item:hover::before,.nav-item1:hover::before,.nav-item2:hover::before {
   content: "";
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: transparent;
  left:254px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 25px;
  margin-top:-70px;
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 -25px 0 0 white;
  transform:rotate(-180deg); 
  transform:rotatex(-180deg); 
}

.nav-item:hover::after {
   content: "";
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: transparent;
  left:253px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 25px;
  margin-top:39.1px;
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 -25px 0 0 white;
  
 
}

.nav-item1:hover::after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: transparent;
  left:253px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 25px;
  margin-top:38.7px;
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 -25px 0 0 white;
 
  
}

.nav-item2:hover::after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: transparent;
  left:253px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 25px;
  margin-top:38.7px;
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 -25px 0 0 white;
  
  
}
.nav-item:hover,.nav-item1:hover,.nav-item2:hover {
  background-color: brown;
  color: black;
 
  background-color: white;
  border-radius:40px 0 0 40px;
}



body {
    background: brown;
}

.main-content {
    
    border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
    height: 107%;
    background-color: white;
}

.new {
    background-color: brown;
}

ul {
  background-color: white;

  
}

@media all and (max-width:768px){
  .main-content{
  width:155%;
  margin-left:-49%;
  margin-right:-10%;
  }
  
  
}
@media all and (min-width:1280px){
  .main-content{
  
  width:200%;
  margin-left:-83%;
  height:120%;
  }
  
  
}
```

```html
  <div class="app">
      <nav class="navigation">
        <div class="nav-content">
       
          <ul class="new">
            <span class="logo">Logo</span>
            <hr />
            
              <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#"></a>
                Home
              </li>
            
            
              <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#"> </a>
                Rate plans
              </li>
           
              <li class="nav-item"><a href="#"></a>
                Bookings
              </li>
          
           
              <li class="nav-item"><a href="#"></a>
                Apartments
              </li>
          
            
              <li class="nav-item"><a href="#"></a>
                Pricing
              </li>
           
            <hr />
            
              <li class="nav-item1"><a href="#"></a>
                Support
              </li>
         
            
              <li class="nav-item2"><a href="#"></a>
                LogOut
              </li>
           
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <main>
        <div class="main-content"></div>
      </main>
    </div>
```

Comment: It's not excatly what I want to achieve. But I'm impressed. Good work! Thank you!

Comment: Thank You.I am very happy to help!

Comment: You have to adjust the elements according to screen size.